# Problema con el llamado de variables de un YML en SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

Tengo un archivo **properties.yml**, con la información que se evidencia a continuación:

```
clave:
  location: "ap"
  apiKey: "QmZ6LvNqzsSSgTTLj1k7ncbaVRumlJ5XgBvadf_7MQaH"
```

la información es llamada desde un controller, que tiene la siguiente información:

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping("/file")
public class StorageController {

    @Autowired
    StorageConfig storageConfig;

    @Autowired
    StorageService storageService;

    @Value("${clave.apiKey}")
    private String apiKey;

    @Value("${clave.serviceInstanceId}")
    private String serviceInstanceId;

    @Value("${clave.endpointUrl}")
    private String endpointUrl;

    @Value("${clave.location}")
    private String location;

    AmazonS3 client = storageConfig.createClient(apiKey, "crn:v1:bluemix:public:cloud-object-storage:global:a/ef304b2c20b5447eac59a8bb3e85812c:15494859-a02d-45d7-9803-e24c7dfcd5fc::", "https://s3.ap.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud", location);

    @PostMapping("/upload") // //new annotation since 4.3
    public String singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        try {
            storageService.uploadFile(client, file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "redirect:/uploadStatus";
    }
}
```

Y sucede que sale un error cuando llamo al apiKey, que tengo creado en properties. Mientras que cuando realizo el llamado de location, no me presenta problema en el método createClient.

¿Saben si estoy cometiendo un error con al momento de llamar los datos? o ¿Existe otra manera de hacer el llamado? Les agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy seguro porqué está funcionando con 'location', en ambos casos debería  fallar.

Sucede que estás intentando introducir lógica (ejecutar el método createClient) en la etapa de resolución de dependencias de Springboot. En esta etapa los valores de apiKey y Location no se han asignado porque @Value es una etiqueta de Runtime. En otras palabras, en ese punto en el que el método las usa ambas variables tienen valor null.

Puedes:

1. Ejecutar esa lógica de createCliend dentro del método singleFileUpload y ya va a tomar ambos valores
2. Inyectar la dependencia por constructor y no por parámetro, algo como:

```
    private StorageConfig storageConfig;
    private StorageService storageService;
    private AmazonS3 client;
    
    @Value("${clave.apiKey}")
        private String apiKey;
    @Value("${clave.location}")
        private String location;
    
    @Autowired
      public StorageController(StorageConfig storageConfig, StorageService storageService) {
        this.storageConfig = storageConfig;
        this.storageService = storageService;
        client = storageConfig.createClient(apiKey, 
   "crn:v1:bluemix:public:cloud-object-storage:global:a/ef304b2c20b5447eac59a8bb3e85812c:15494859-a02d-45d7-9803-e24c7dfcd5fc::", "https://s3.ap.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud", location);
        
      }
```

Esto es lo que interpreto que puede estar pasando, sin embargo sería mejor que edites la pregunta e incluyas el error que te sale, así las respuestas pueden ser un poco más acertadas a lo que necesitas.